# Apache Chroot - ibase_connect failure

Tags: apache, firebird, interbase, chroot

Apache 2, running mod_chroot. Can access basic html and php script fine.

This test script works fine using cli php, so I know connection string is fine.

```
$host = '127.0.0.1:pubdata';
$password ="*******";
$username="SYSDBA";
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password);
.. do query etc
```

However, when I run this under Chrooted Apache, it returns an error message:

`Warning: ibase_connect(): Can't access lock files' directory /tmp/firebird in /html/app/webroot/test2.php`

This seems really strange. /tmp/firebird exists and is used by firebird when script by CLI.

When I compiled the PHP I used --with-interbase=/opt/firebird/

Hope this makes sense and someone has a thought!

Comment: can you connect to this server locally using isql/isql-fb with a non-root user? can you connect to this server from other machine in the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Always localhost: in front or another external IP before connecting and also restart apache + firebird before connecting

My guess is that you use Classic or SuperClassic firebird and it tries to attach to /tmp and db directly

http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Have-you-tried-firebird-2-5-SuperClassic-from-the-packages-td3053790.html

ps:
Also Once chrooted, Apache cannot access anything located above ChrootDir

Comment: Just as a clarification - it is superclassic and the problem was definitely that the client was not accessible from outside Chrooted environment.